# How to get ONE of the lowest values from large table LUA?

Tags: math, lua, lua-table

```
playerElement = { 
    { itemName="Ammo clip", value="30" },
    { itemName="Ammo clip", value="30" },
    { itemName="Ammo clip", value="30" },
}
```

How do I retrieve either the first item in the table (when all item values are equal) and if not the item with the lowest value, so I can substract it with 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first scan the entire table to do that, given your table's structure.

```
local lowestIndex = 0;
local lowestValue = false;
for k, v in ipairs(playerElement) do
    if not lowestValue or v.value < lowestValue then
        lowestIndex = k;
        lowestValue = v;
    end
end

playerElement[lowestIndex].value = lowestValue - 1;
```

P.S. I'm typing on the go, so sorry for any syntax errors.

Comment: I got proposed reviews supposedly correcting syntax errors by removing semicolons - they are not syntax errors, but merely optional line endings. They are quite acceptable in Lua (or were the last time I checked, which was around Lua 5.2).

Answer (score 2):

i'm starting to learn Lua and I use the [underscore-lua](https://github.com/jtarchie/underscore-lua) library to solve your problem.

```
local _ = require 'underscore'

-- here you define the playerElement table
-- playerElement = {}

-- create table of values
local values = _.map(playerElement, function(t) return t.value end)

-- get max and min values
local max = _.max(values)
local min = _.min(values)

 -- get first item when all the values are equal, if not the item with the lowest value
 if max == min then
   return playerElement[1]
 else
   return _.findWhere(playerElement, {value=tostring(min)})
 end
```